# Sound output problem on HP pavillion g6 2229TU in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: sound, hp-pavilion

How can i solve Sound output problem on HP pavilion g6 2229TU in Ubuntu 10.04? Give some reliable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things i have found useful from community help and i will paste here. The full debugging link is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting). here are the explanations I find relevant

**6. Is the sound card physically installed and recognized by your hardware?**

Open a terminal and type

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
```

This should output some information about your audio hardware. An example is below.

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff01
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
        Memory at dc440000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
        Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Most people, especially laptop users, have a built-in sound card for their computer on the motherboard. If yours is built-in and isn't showing up in this step, then you probably need to enable it in your BIOS. When you first reboot your computer, there's usually a key sequence listed telling you how to enter the BIOS configuration screen. Since all BIOS's are differenct, you'll need to sort through your BIOS and enable the built in sound card. If you need help with this, you should ask at ubuntuforums.org.

If you are not using a built in sound card, and this step does not show your audio card, the card may be seated incorrectly on your motherboard, or may be bad or otherwise incompatible with your motherboard. You will probably want to test the card in another computer to see if it works there.

**7. Is my sound card supported by the Ubuntu sound system?**

Ubuntu uses the Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA) for managing sound output. There is a listing of all of the sound cards supported by ALSA at http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Main . You should look for the information that was listed by the command in the previous step. If it happens that your sound card is not supported by ALSA, you have two options: obtain a new sound card that is supported by ALSA, or contact the ALSA developers and request support for your sound card.